# Xpath Creation in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have a Element Xpath

```
//img[@onclick="EditResource(this,'10','0');"]
```

I need to use this in a loop where i will replace 10 with a variable i.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@onclick='EditResource(this,'" +  i +"','0');']"))
```

But it is giving an error No such Element as EditResource is in the double quotes.

Comment: Please show the HTML document you are selecting from.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use all the specifics (like the params of the function) from the `onclick` event, as those may change causing your `xpath` to fail.
You could use the `contains()` method inside the `xpath` and this way, even if the parameters change (for any reason), your element is still found:

```
.//img[contains(@onclick, 'EditResource')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily escape the " from your locator like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@onclick=\"EditResource(this,'" +  i +"','0');\"]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy to look this is...

`String str1 = "EditResource(this,'";
 String str2 = "','0')']";
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(str1+i+str2));`

And, you can also do it in one line

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@onclick=\"EditResource(this,'" +  i +"','0');\"]"));`

`\"` gives you `'` while running the xpath.